# Error:(44, 5) error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype

Tags: android

Indefinite.java
This is my main code and there is someproblem with the code.Any help will very appreciated.

```
package mycompanycom.indefinite;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;


public class Indefinite extends ActionBarActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_indefinite);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_indefinite, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
Intent intent=new Intent(this,DisplayMessageActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
   }
}
```

This is my xml for my first project.

activity_indefinite.xml

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"  
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"     
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".Indefinite">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/the_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/INDEFINITE"
    android:onClick="onClick"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:tint="#55ff0000"
    android:src="@drawable/images"
    android:layout_below="@+id/the_button"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="85dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is my second activity code programmatically written

DisplayMessageActivity.java

```
package mycompanycom.indefinite;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;


public class DisplayMessageActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
   //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

In my second activity I have written getIntent() to accept the intent.

Comment: implement a `View.OnClickListner` to your class

Answer (score 1):

`public void onClick(View view)` is part of the `View.OnClickListener` interface. To make your app compile you have to add `implements View.OnClickListener` to the definition of your class

Answer (score 0):

You don't need @override here, because you already mentioned the method name in XML file itself, remove it(@override) before onClick() method and run.